# How to circumvent a browser cache when Cache-Control header is not allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, http, cors, github-api, fetch-api

I'm using the GitHub API to request notifications which need to be up to date. Problem is that my browser often loads the answers to my requests from the browser cache instead of from the Internet, which of course aren't up to date.
In order to prevent this and tell the browser not to use the cache, I've read that one is supposed to use the `Cache-Control` header.
Problem is that the GitHub API doesn't seem to have the `Cache-Control` header in its `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, so I'm not not allowed to use the `Cache-Control` header in my requests.

So, how am I supposed to prevent my browser to load responses from the cache if I'm not allowed to use the `Cache-Control` header? Why does the GitHub API forbids the `Cache-Control` header in the first place, any good reason for that?

Just to give a bit more context, I'm using the fetch API in JavaScript and tried the code below

```
res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/notifications', {method: 'Get', 
    headers: {    
        'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json', 
        'authorization': "token " + token,  
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'               
}});
```

And I get the error message:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.github.com/notifications' from origin 
>   'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request
>   header  field cache-control is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in  preflight response.

Could you please recommend me the best solution for my problem?

Comment: Can you try cache busting it with a query parameter? `https://api.github.com/notifications?cachebust=123456`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [notifications page](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/) on the GitHub docs...

> Notifications are optimized for polling with the Last-Modified header. If there are no new notifications, you will see a 304 Not Modified response, leaving your current rate limit untouched. There is an X-Poll-Interval header that specifies how often (in seconds) you are allowed to poll. In times of high server load, the time may increase. Please obey the header.

And they also provide this example using curl...

```sh
# Add authentication to your requests
curl -I https://api.github.com/notifications
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Thu, 25 Oct 2012 15:16:27 GMT
X-Poll-Interval: 60

# Pass the Last-Modified header exactly
curl -I https://api.github.com/notifications
   -H "If-Modified-Since: Thu, 25 Oct 2012 15:16:27 GMT"
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
X-Poll-Interval: 60
```

They're using a `Last-Modified` header which contains the date the notifications were last updated. You echo that date back to the server in your request using the `If-Modified-Since` header and if the content hasn't changed you'll get a "304 Not Modified" status response back containing no content.

As the text says, they also supply a polling interval header which you should read and ensure you're notification update function does not run more frequently than the interval that specifies, which in their example is "60" (seconds) meaning "not more than once a minute".

A note on the other answer - you should definitely not use a cache bust query parameter. GitHub are providing a mechanism to control caching and also to control the load on their servers to maintain availability. Disregarding this causes problems for everyone and is probably against their terms of use.

Comment: Thank you, wanted to build in the X-Poll-Interval at a later point. I wanted to keep it simple at this stage in the development until I get my head around the basic stuff.
Having said that, couldn't you still use a cache bust query parameter after one minute to ensure that the cache is ignored?

Comment: If you use that you'll invalidate a perfectly good cached version. You only want the effort of downloading notifications and updating stuff if things have actually changed which is what If-Modified-Since gives you. Cache bust will blindly download the notifications every time.

Answer (score -1):

So I solved the problem thanks to zero298 comment by using a query parameter in the request

```
let cachebust = window.localStorage.getItem("cachebust253");
if(cachebust === null) {cachebust = 0;}
res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/notifications?cache_bust=${cachebust}', {method: 'Get', 
    headers: {    
        'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json', 
        'authorization': "token " + token,                
}});
window.localStorage.setItem("cachebust253", parseInt(cachebust)+1);
```

edit: this no valid solution though, as in case of github it doesn't respect the github api policy. One has to respect the x-poll-interval header of the github api as pointed out by dezfowler

Comment: Please see my answer on this. There is a right way to do it provided in the GitHub API.